# Why isn't my TakeLimit honored by TableQuery?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'd like to fetch top *n* rows from my Azure Table with a simple TableQuery. But with the code below, all rows are fetched regardless of my limit with the Take.

What am I doing wrong?

```
int entryLimit = 5;

var table = GetFromHelperFunc();

TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>()
    .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "MyPK"))
    .Take(entryLimit);

List<FeedEntry> entryList = new List<FeedEntry>();
TableQuerySegment<FeedEntry> currentSegment = null;

while (currentSegment == null || currentSegment.ContinuationToken != null)
{
    currentSegment = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(query, this.EntryResolver, currentSegment != null ? currentSegment.ContinuationToken : null);
    entryList.AddRange(currentSegment.Results);
}


Trace.WriteLine(entryList.Count) // <-- Why does this exceed my limit?
```

Comment: Accepted answer isn't correct - see @Fabrzio's answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Take method on the storage SDK doesn't work like it would in LINQ. Imagine you do something like this:

```
TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>()
                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "temp"))
                .Take(5);
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

When you start iterating over `result` you'll initially get only 5 items. But underneath, if you keep iterating over the `result`, the SDK will keep querying the table (and proceed to the next 'page' of 5 items).

If I have 5000 items in my table, this code will output all 5000 items (and underneath the SDK will do 1000 requests and fetch 5 items per request):

```
TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>()
                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "temp"))
                .Take(5);
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(item.RowKey);
}
```

The following code will fetch exactly 5 items in 1 request and stop there:

```
TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>()
                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "temp"))
                .Take(5);
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.RowKey);
    index++;
    if (index == 5)
        break;
}
```

Actually, the **Take()** method sets the page size or the "take count" ([TakeCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.takecount.aspx) property on TableQuery). But it's still up to you to stop iterating on time if you only want 5 records.

In your example, you should modify the while loop to stop when reaching the TakeCount (which you set by calling Take):

```
while (entryList.Count < query.TakeCount && (currentSegment == null || currentSegment.ContinuationToken != null))
{
    currentSegment = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(query, currentSegment != null ? currentSegment.ContinuationToken : null);
    entryList.AddRange(currentSegment.Results);
}
```

Comment: Sandrino, are you sure about the answer? In my test Take works correctly.  Perhaps you are referencing a old and bugged version of StorageClient  https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/144

Comment: Nuget 9.1.0 still has the issue and had to follow the recommendation here.

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK Storage Client Library 2.0 had a bug in Take implementation. It was fixed in ver 2.0.4.
Read last comments at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx

[EDIT]
Original MSDN post no longer available. Still present on WebArchive:
http://web.archive.org/web/20200722170914/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsazurestorage/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive

Comment: This link is now broken.

Comment: Added WebArchive link