# How do I limit rows returned for a query using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table library?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I need to implement pagination functionality. How do I use TableQuery of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table to limit the number of rows returned? (similar to SQL's Top or LINQ's Take)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Take()` method (Ref : Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.take.aspx) of `TableQuery` class for you to achieve result limitation. But it doesn't work exactly same in LINQ. Explanation in [Why isn't my TakeLimit honored by TableQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452801/why-isnt-my-takelimit-honored-by-tablequery) by Sandrino Di Mattia should help you understand how `Take()` works in `TableQuery` class.